# Stopping a sub when the required text isn't found

Tags: excel, vba, find

I am currently linking lots of subs together to format headings in excel for upload to other dashboard software.  The headings need to be in a certain order.  I am running several subs triggered by a command button to search for the heading text in a sepcified range of cells.  having trouble with if the heading isn't found which sometimes happens as the data is downloaded from brandwatch and if nothing returns for that particular subject in Brandwatch then the heading isn't in the downloaded data file.  I want the macro to stop when the required text isn't found in the range.

I am only just learning VB and have no idea how to stop the next sub from running if the specific text isnt found.  As it stands at the minute it is putting in another heading as the next subroutine is a copy active column and then goto another specific column and paste.

The message 'The Value you are searching for is not available' comes up but then the next sub pastes the wrong heading in when I just want all the macros to stop at that point.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks Sylly
the offending Subroutine is below

```
Sub FIND_POTENTIAL_IRRELEVANT_MENTIONS()

'============================
'FIND POTENTIAL_IRRELEVANT_MENTIONS
'============================

Dim MyValue As Variant

On Error Resume Next
Range("CT9:HD9").Find(What:="Market Insight Report").Select
On Error GoTo 0
MyValue = ActiveCell.Value
If MyValue = "" Then
    MsgBox "The Value you are searching for is not available"
Else
    MsgBox MyValue & " found in " & ActiveCell.Address
End If
           
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want the macro you presented to stop, just add `Exit Sub` after `MsgBox "The Value you are searching for is not available"`. If there are other macros called by the same sub, you must create a `Public` variable, let us say `Public boolAllStop As Boolean` on top of a standard module. Than, all the subs in discussion will start with the line `If boolAllStop then Exit Sub`. And you must make it `True` before exiting in the sub you shared. Take also care to make it `False` when will run the code next time... If not clear what I tried explaining do  not hesitate to ask for clarifications.

Comment: @FaneDuru if you want the procedure to completely stop (not just a sub procedure) you can use `End` instead of `Exit Sub`. This will stop  the macro for good.

Comment: Thanks I managed to solve the problem by removing some code so the debug comes up if the text isn't found.  Works for me.  Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Damian: Yes, you are right. I always use `End Sub`. Now, it came into my mind like a bad reflex...